# TurboJpeg: No speed improvements

Tags: performance, libjpeg, libjpeg-turbo, turbojpeg

I'm on a 64-bit CentOS 6.4 machine.  I have a simple benchmark that reads a JPEG into memory or writes a JPEG.  I was previously using libjpeg.  Now, I installed TurboJpeg, recompiled, and I see no performance improvement.  I re-linked against libturbojpeg, I changed the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to where the libturbo libraries are (in /opt/libjpeg-turbo), I did everything I can think of, but the performance is exactly the same.

Why is this?

Could it be tha tthe libjpeg.so files that were already in /usr/lib64 on my machine were already from libjpeg-turbo?  That's the only thing I can think of.

However, how can I know for sure that libjpeg-turbo is no faster, and I'm not doing something wrong?

Comment: Depending on how much image processing you are doing the disk I/O could be the limiting factor. Consider trying putting the files on a RAMdisk and see if the two libraries exhibit  a difference then.

Comment: No difference from RAMdisk or regular disk.

Comment: Is there a way I can tell if the libjpeg I'm linking against is from libturbo, or the regular libjpeg?

Comment: could you leak some of the code and the build command you are using? But in fact, you might have to get a fresh libjpeg to make sure that you do in fact not have a libjpeg-turbo named libjpeg.